# Serialising a list of dataclasses: str always calls repr

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'd like to serialise dataclasses to strings. That's easy enough with `dataclasses.asdict` and creating a custom `__str__` method. It works perfectly, even for classes that have other dataclasses or lists of them as members. However, calling `str` on a list of dataclasses produces the `repr` version. I'd like `str` to produce the serialised form and `repr` to stay as it is.

```
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict


@dataclass
class Ser:
    def __repr__(self):
        print('repr called')
        return json.dumps(asdict(self))

    def __str__(self):
        print('str called')
        return json.dumps(asdict(self))


@dataclass(repr=False)
class C(Ser):
    i: int

    def __str__(self):
        print('child str called')
        return super().__str__()


list_in = json.loads('[{"i": 1}, {"i": 2}]')
data = [C(**i) for i in list_in]
print(data)
print(repr(data))
print(str(data))
```

The output of the script above is:

```
repr called
repr called
[{"i": 1}, {"i": 2}]
repr called
repr called
[{"i": 1}, {"i": 2}]
repr called
repr called
[{"i": 1}, {"i": 2}]
```

Curiously, none of the `str` methods are ever called even when explicitly asking for the string version through the list. If the `repr=False` is removed, the `repr` is overwritten and none of the custom methods are called.

The wanted output would be:

```
>>> data  # I guess inspecting with the command line always calls repr
[C(i=1), C(i=2)]
>>> repr(data)
[C(i=1), C(i=2)]
>>> str(data)
[{"i": 1}, {"i": 2}]
```

Comment: [The default implementation defined by the built-in type object calls object.__repr__().](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Comment: You never explicitly ask for ``str`` of your data, you ask for ``str`` of the list of your data. Lists implicitly call ``repr`` on their elements. Even if you circumvent this for the top-level or any list, intermediate objects are free to decide how to react to ``str`` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `str` of a `list` calls the `repr` of its elements, that's  just how it is implemented. Nothing about how you implement the elements' classes is going to change that. So if you don't want to meddle with the dataclass's `__repr__`, you would have to use your own collection class instead of `list`, e.g.:

```
class StrList(list):
    def __str__(self):
        return '[' + ', '.join(str(x) for x in self) + ']'


lst = StrList([1, '1'])
str(lst)
# '[1, 1]'
repr(lst)
# "[1, '1']"
```

If you really want to change the `__str__` of a built-in type like `list` , you could look at [`forbiddenfruit`](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit)

Comment: So it seems. A bit weird, but I'm sure there are reasons for it. Thanks!

Comment: You can see in the given example, that the `str` of elements loses some information about their types. That might be one reason. Imagine strings containing commas within lists. You wouldn't know anything about such lists from their representation.

Comment: True, but in this context I'd want it to produce a JSON-like output, so information on the type would not be lost. Good point.